# Kubernetes IP conflict

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ip, conflict

I have the following context: There is a GCP VPC interconnect to the company where are a lot of services with ip address in the range of 10.7.114.0/23. Also in the GCP I have Kubernetes pods that consuming the mentioned on-premise 10.7.114.0/23 services.

The Kubernetes range is 10.194.0.0/19 and when from a pod I want to access the on-premise 10.7.114.0/23 services I've been blocked. The traceroute tracks to the ip 10.194.0.1 and after that is blocked.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: can you telnet or ping those ips from the kubernetes pods ?

Comment: no, the ping/telnet is just hanging (like somewhere the SYN packets are eaten)

Comment: there is an issue with permissions, in your services, if you don't have a NAT from the kubernetes pods, check with which IP they are trying to telnet from, and add those IPS to the security groups of the other service. Typically it is the nodes IP